# Loading fabric js subclass of fabric.image with an image filter applied

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem of loading the image filter that is saved to my subclassed image object.  Here is the code for my subclass:

```
fabric.TopImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {

    type: 'top-image',

    initialize: function (element, options) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
        this.set('name', 'top');
        this.set('lockUniScaling', true);
    },

    toObject: function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), { name: this.name });
    }

});

fabric.TopImage.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function (img) {
        callback && callback(new fabric.TopImage(img, object));
    });
};

fabric.TopImage.async = true;
```

This works fine without applying any filters.

I add a filter to an instance of this subclass by using something like:

```
objectToFilter.filters[0] = new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite({threshold: 20, distance: 20});
objectToFilter.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Saving the object passes the filter object with a type, threshold and distance.

However loading this object causes an error in the all.js file of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'applyTo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you never call the Image.fromObject function there, filters are never initialized and they can't be applied. In order to get filters to work out as expected, use this function instead:

```
fabric.TopImage.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function (img) {
            var oImg = new fabric.TopImage(img);
            oImg._initConfig(object);
            oImg._initFilters(object);
            callback(oImg);
    });
};
```